# Ip Address detected but fatal error occuring

Tags: php

I am able to get my machine ip address at localhost.
But a fatal error is occuring.

I try many times but I can't fix it.

```
<?php 
    function getclientip() 
    {

       if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
       {
         //ip from share internet
         $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
       }
       elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
       {
         //ip pass from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
       }
       else
       {
         $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       }

      return $ip;
    }

      echo 'User Real IP - '.getclientip();
?>
```

Any one can help me reduce this error?

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getclientip() (previously declared in
>   Z:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\function.php:4) in
>   Z:\xampp\htdocs\Mysite\function.php on line 19

Comment: as per error you already defined *getclientip()*, rename function name

Comment: Now how i can solve it?

Comment: @aasabkhan: By only declaring the function once, not twice.

Comment: It showing your real ip ::1

Answer (score 3):

The function `getclientip()` is already defined in `function.php` at line 4 as the error message states.

Three solutions can be applied to get rid of this issue:

1) **Use Existing:** Use existing function rather than writing a new function.

2) **Write a new function with different name:** If purpose of the new function is different, use a different name.
 e.g. `getclientipaddress()`

3) **Define function only if there isn't a function with same name:** Write a function and allow it to execute only if a function with same name does not exist.

There is a PHP function: [function_exists()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) which checks if the function with same name is already defined.

So, you can avoid Fatal Error if the function is already defined.

**Code to check existence of function:**

```
if (! function_exists('getclientip')) {
 function getclientip() {
 }
}
```